# Does anybody tell me what changes need to be done here if I want a triangle at the top not bottom?

Tags: html, css, mask

```css
.a {
  /* you can change this variable */
  --arrow-width: 30px;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000) 0 0/100% calc(100% - var(--arrow-width)) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 0 50%, #000 50.1% 100%) calc(50% - var(--arrow-width) / 2) 100% / var(--arrow-width) var(--arrow-width) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 0 50%, #000 50.1% 100%) calc(50% + var(--arrow-width) / 2) 100% / var(--arrow-width) var(--arrow-width) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/600/360) 50% 50% / cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Does anybody tell me what changes need to be done here if I want a triangle at the top not bottom?

Comment: i'm sure you can try something yourself before asking us. If you were able to build this css effect it's trivial to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to change the positions of the various gradients.

The first one's vertical position should start at the "arrow width" var.

Both the others vertical positions should be set to 0 instead of 100%.

You also need to change the direction of the last two gradients from "to top" to "to bottom" so the arrow will be pointing up.

Lastly, you should also add "padding-top" with the height of the "arrow width" var as to not lose that much of the image size.

```css
.a {
  /* you can change this variable */
  --arrow-width: 30px;
  padding-top: var(--arrow-width);
  margin-top: calc(var(--arrow-width) * -1); /* added to make the image aligned to the top */
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000) 0 var(--arrow-width)/100% calc(100% - var(--arrow-width)) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 0 50%, #000 50.1% 100%) calc(50% - var(--arrow-width) / 2) 0 / var(--arrow-width) var(--arrow-width) no-repeat, 
          linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 0 50%, #000 50.1% 100%) calc(50% + var(--arrow-width) / 2) 0 / var(--arrow-width) var(--arrow-width) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/600/360) 50% 50% / cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: but there is a some problem with this code images gone downward so they don't alleged

Comment: then remove the "padding-top: var(--arrow-width);" I've added. the image will be a bit smaller because the arrow will take space, but it'll keep the overall height.

Comment: in this code the image goes down it is not aligned with the rest of the images i want the image to not go down and remain aligned with the rest of the image is it possible if yes then please tell me how https://prnt.sc/20niz1m

Comment: i have removed the padding but nothing will happen

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. you don't want he arrow to push the image down. the easiest way to avoid it is to add a negative margin on top. something like this: margin-top: calc(var(--arrow-width) * -1);. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: yes its working 
Thankyou So Much Uri Chachick You are very helpful